# plugin/contain listening on UDP

Tags: networking, security

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and am surprised to see this:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54877           0.0.0.0:*                           6451/plugin-contain
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           6721/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::53613                :::*                                6451/plugin-contain
```

`plugin-contain` wasn't there when I first installed Ubuntu, but I've installed a few things since but didn't expect a new service to be listening.

What is this? Anything suspicious?

Comment: It appears that it's part of Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-is-plugin-container